# Ascending Form numbers in Yii

Tags: php, yii

In Yii I am doing a form in which the form has input fields for user details.I have made necessary input fields for all those fields.Where a user can submit all the values.Now I have a field where it will show the form number which will not be entered by user.It will be generated randomly with ascending order like
for the 1st form it will be like this `FORM:001,` For the second form it will be like this `FORM:002` and it will go on.
Now I want that the form number will be like  `Form:001` so how to do that?HAny help and suggestions will be highly appriciable.

**[UPDATED]**

```
  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'id'); ?>
    <?php echo Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertId();?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'id'); ?>
  </div>
```

This is the code for view > _form.php file.
and the result is `ID 0`

Comment: Is it actual random ascending or just ascending that you need? Are you inserting this in a database? More information please.

Comment: ya actually I want that in ascending order.just like Form:001,Form:002,Form:003,Form:004....
Actually this number will popup when user will go for inserting a form.

Comment: Do you need to display that to the user?

Comment: yes..So that user can track the form by this form number

Answer (score 0):

What you need is either of the following:

```
$maxFormId= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('max(id) as max')
->from('tbl_yourtable')
->queryScalar();
$yourFormId = "Form:".($maxFormId+ 1);
```

or alternatively run the following after the insert, and only display the form id then:

```
$yourFormId = "Form:".Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertId();
```

UPDATE:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new YourModel;

        if(isset($_POST['YourForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['YourForm'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

On the above:

```
$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
```

automatically gives you the last ID inserted so you can just put the following in your view:

```
echo "Form:".$id;
```

Comment: I thnk this should be use in view file,or in controller ,the value will be assigned?

Comment: The value would be used in your view file, yes.

Comment: thanks @Avanche for your quick reply but when I tried <?php echo Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertId(); ?> It is showing 0 every time.How to solve this?

Comment: @avanche...Still it is not working.It is showing 0 in my _form.php file.I want the last insert id in _form.php file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8236/discussion-between-newuser-and-avanche)

Comment: How you solved that? I also get 0 using Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID()