# Getting last inserted value in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have already made a model for form.In that the fields were like

```
id
firstname
lastname
description
created_at
updated_at
created_by
updated_by
```

I have made necessary CRUD for Form.Now I want to get one extra field for last inserted id in view  file.So how to get that value?To get that value should I make  any necessary changes in CRUD?Any help and suggestions will be highly appriciable.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456132/getting-last-inserted-id-from-mysql-in-yii and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436264/ascending-form-numbers-in-yii

Answer (score 24):

You can get the last inserted ID like this:

```
Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertId();
```

See the [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#getLastInsertID-detail) for more information.

Comment: ID not Id. with capital D Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to get the id that was assigned to the model that you just saved, then after you do `$model->save()`, simply do `$model->id` to get it back.

Answer (score 3):

If `$model->id` wouldn't work then use `Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertId()` or `getPrimaryKey()`.

Comment: `Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertId()` seems better, as it can be used anywhere outside model (like in migrations) and does not fall into conserns discussed [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6566-how-to-know-the-last-record-id-inserted/page__view__findpost__p__33653). But, anywhere -- nice answer (+!). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can also get the last inserted id of another model.

```
$std_id = Students::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'admission_no DESC','limit' => 1));

            foreach($std_id as $f) {

                echo  "Last Inserted Admission No:".$f['admission_no'];
                }
```

or

you can last inserted id in the  same model

```
Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Yii2` last inserted id can be get using

```
Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertedID();
```

added for the people looking for the answer of same question in `yii2`

Answer (score 0):

Reference Link : [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12776-get-last-inserted-id/)

```
$model->primaryKey or
$model->id // this is your primary key item
```

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 last inserted id can be get using

```
Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();
```

not use

```
Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertedID();
```